# Mounting a Kubernetes Volume with Quarkus

Tags: kubernetes, quarkus, persistent-volumes

I am trying to mount a volume to a Pod so that one deployment can write to it, and another deployment can read from it.  I am using MiniKube with Docker on Ubuntu.  I am running `./mvnw clean package -Dquarkus.kubernetes.deploy=true`.

From the Quarkus documentation, it seems pretty straightforward, but I'm running into trouble.

When I add this line `quarkus.kubernetes.mounts.my-volume.path=/volumePath` to my application.properties, I get the following error:

```sh
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:1.6.0.Final:build (default) on project getting-started: Failed to build quarkus application: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
[ERROR]         [error]: Build step io.quarkus.kubernetes.deployment.KubernetesDeployer#deploy threw an exception: io.dekorate.deps.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Failure executing: POST at: https://IP:8443/apis/apps/v1/namespaces/default/deployments. Message: Deployment.apps "getting-started" is invalid: spec.template.spec.containers[0].volumeMounts[0].name: Not found: "my-volume". Received status: Status(apiVersion=v1, code=422, details=StatusDetails(causes=[StatusCause(field=spec.template.spec.containers[0].volumeMounts[0].name, message=Not found: "my-volume", reason=FieldValueNotFound, additionalProperties={})], group=apps, kind=Deployment, name=getting-started, retryAfterSeconds=null, uid=null, additionalProperties={}), kind=Status, message=Deployment.apps "getting-started" is invalid: spec.template.spec.containers[0].volumeMounts[0].name: Not found: "my-volume", metadata=ListMeta(_continue=null, remainingItemCount=null, resourceVersion=null, selfLink=null, additionalProperties={}), reason=Invalid, status=Failure, additionalProperties={}).
```

When I add `quarkus.kubernetes.config-map-volumes.my-volume.config-map-name=my-volume` (along with the previous statement), the error goes away, but the pod does not start.  Running "kubectl describe pods" returns:

```sh
Normal   Scheduled    <unknown>          default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/getting-started-859d89fc8-tbg6w to minikube
  Warning  FailedMount  14s (x6 over 30s)  kubelet, minikube  MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "my-volume" : configmap "my-volume" not found
```

Does it look like the volume is not being set in the YAML file?

So my question is, how can I set the name of the volume in application.properties, so I can have a volume mounted in the Pod?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you look at your [kubernetes.yml and kubernetes.json files under `target/kubernetes`](https://quarkus.io/guides/kubernetes#kubernetes)

For the first error. It looks like `my-volume` needs to exist in your cluster either as a [Persistent Volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/).

For the second error `quarkus.kubernetes.config-map-volumes.my-volume.config-map-name=my-volume` is meant to be used as a [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/) so the actual ConfigMap needs to be defined/exist in your cluster.